# Div is not centered like rest of the same family

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to do this website to imitate a online survey maker where you can create a survey with different kinds of questions.

I have done some kinds but there is a problem with the question with the **stars**. I have put the same CSS code to put that question in the center and and do the same size border with the others but for some reason it is not working.

I tried to figure out what is wrong but I couldn't figure it out. I tried some things but they didn't work and now I am asking if someone had similar issue or knows how to fix this to assist a bit. I can imagine it is something simple but I just don't know what the issue is.

My code is the same for the creation of all questions and it should work the same as the others.

This is my code:

```js
  const questionnaire = document.getElementById('questionaire');

 function newOpQuestion() {
    questionnaire.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
        `<div class="opQuestion">
    <div class="questionName" contenteditable="true">Your Question</div>
    <button class="remove-qu" type="button">remove Question</button>
    <ul></ul>
    <button class="add-li" type="button">Add Option</button>    
   </div>`);
    newOption(questionnaire.querySelector("div.opQuestion:last-child ul"));


    let removeOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.remove-li');
    let removeQuestions = document.querySelectorAll('.remove-qu');

    if (removeOptions) {
        removeOptions.forEach((item) => {
            item.onclick = function () { this.parentNode.remove(); }

        })
    }
    if (removeQuestions) {
        removeQuestions.forEach((item) => {
            item.onclick = function () { this.parentNode.remove(); }

        })
    }
 }

 function newShAnQuestion() {
    questionnaire.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
        `<div class="shAnQuestion">
    <div class="questionName" contenteditable="true">Your Question</div>
    <button class="remove-qu" type="button">remove Question</button>
    <ul></ul>
    <input class="shAnTextbox "type="text"></input>
   </div>`);

    let removeQuestions = document.querySelectorAll('.remove-qu');

    if (removeQuestions) {
        removeQuestions.forEach((item) => {
            item.onclick = function () { this.parentNode.remove(); }

        })
    }
 }

 function newNumQuestion() {
    questionnaire.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
        `<div class='numQuestion'>
        <div class="questionName" contenteditable="true">Your Question</div> 
        <button class="remove-qu" type="button">remove Question</button> <div class="numbers">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" id="5" disabled><label for="5">5</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" id="4" disabled><label for="4">4</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" id="3" disabled><label for="3">3</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" id="2" disabled><label for="2">2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" id="1" disabled><label for="1">1</label> 
 </div> </div>`);

    let removeQuestions = document.querySelectorAll('.remove-qu');

    if (removeQuestions) {
        removeQuestions.forEach((item) => {
            item.onclick = function () { this.parentNode.remove(); }

        })
    }
 }

 function newStarQuestion() {
    questionnaire.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
       `<table> <tr> <td>
        <div class="starQuestion"> <form>
        <div class="questionName" contenteditable="true">Your Question</div> 
        <button class="remove-qu" type="button">remove Question</button> 
        <div class="numbers">
        <input class="star star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star" disabled/>
        <label class="star star-5" for="star-5"> </label readonly=" readonly">
        <input class="star star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star" disabled/>
        <label class="star star-4" for="star-4"> </label readonly=" readonly">
        <input class="star star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star" disabled/>
        <label class="star star-3" for="star-3"> </label readonly=" readonly">
        <input class="star star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star" disabled/>
        <label class="star star-2" for="star-2"> </label readonly=" readonly">
        <input class="star star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star" disabled/>
        <label class="star star-1" for="star-1"> </label readonly=" readonly">
         </div> </form> </div> </td> </tr> </table>`);

    let removeQuestions = document.querySelectorAll('.remove-qu');

    if (removeQuestions) {
        removeQuestions.forEach((item) => {
            item.onclick = function () { this.parentNode.remove(); }

        })
    }
 }

 function newOption(q) {
    q.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
        `<li class="optionName">
      <span contenteditable="true">Option</span>
      <input type="checkbox"><span class="remove-li">Remove Option<span>
     </li>`);

 }

 questionnaire.onclick = ev => {
    if (ev.target.tagName === "BUTTON" && ev.target.className === "add-li") {
        newOption(ev.target.closest(".opQuestion").querySelector('ul'))
    }
 }

 document.getElementById("addOpQuButton").onclick = newOpQuestion
 document.getElementById("addShAnButton").onclick = newShAnQuestion
 document.getElementById("addNumButton").onclick = newNumQuestion
 document.getElementById("addStarButton").onclick = newStarQuestion
```

```css
 

   

body {
    background-color: #00ffaa;
 }

 #myText {
    margin: 20px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
 }

 .opQuestion, .shAnQuestion, .numQuestion, .starQuestion {
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: 30px 200px 20px 200px;
    text-align: center;
 }

 .shAnTextbox, .numbers {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
 }

 #addOpQuButton,
 #addShAnButton,
 #addNumButton,
 #addStarButton {
    font-size: 15px;  
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(6, 176, 57);
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: white;
    cursor: default;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 .questionName {
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
 }

 .opQuestion ul li {
    display: block;
 }

 .optionName {
    font-size: 21px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-style: oblique;
 }

 .remove-li {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    background-color: red;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: white;
    cursor: default;
 }

 .remove-qu {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    background-color: red;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: white;
    cursor: default;
 }

 .add-li {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(6, 176, 57);
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
 }

 input.star:checked~label.star:before {
    content: '\f005';
    color: blue;
    transition: all .25s;
 }

 label.star:before {
    content: '\f006';
    font-family: FontAwesome;
 }
```

```html
    
  <h1 id="myText" contenteditable="true">Survey Name</h1>
  <button type="button" id="addOpQuButton">Options</button>
  <button type="button" id="addShAnButton">Short Answer</button>
  <button type="button" id="addNumButton">Number Rating</button>
  <button type="button" id="addStarButton">Star Rating</button>
  <form>
    <div id="questionaire"></div>
  </form>
```

Comment: see the html code you are using, it's not the same as the others

Comment: For some reason you're using a table in star questions ... tables need to be handled carefully, they're not like any other element

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the size of the star-character is too large. It has a size of 18.86px (see screenshot). At the number rating a character only has 8px and therefore the sum of all characters (including the radio-buttons) is less than the available width of "numQuestion"-div (188px).

Make sure that the star is smaller or make the question div (.starQuestion) larger.

Minimum width for the div should be 215px to work.